# Perl Win32::Lanman - Is there a n equivalent?

Tags: perl, winapi

I am upgrading an application on an old windows 2003 server, which used perl 5.6 and I found a script which disconnects users from terminals using Win32::Lanman::WTSEnumerateSessions and Win32::Lanman::WTSQuerySessionInformation. After searching the web I realized that this module wouldn't run properly on perl 5.14 which I wish to use. 
Do you know any equivalent module/s so I could refactor this sctipt? or alternatively a way to make it run under perl 5.14

thanks in advanced,

Roy

Comment: Where are these module? It likely goes quicker to repair/bugfix the existing ones than to come up with a full replacement.

Comment: http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/J/JH/JHELBERG/lanman.1.0.10.0.zip - Nevermind, it's worse than I thought.

Comment: That's a creative build process.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for your replies,
I worked around the problem although I really don't like this solution..
I have decided to divide this script from the others and run it with the system command using the full path to the old perl interpreter.

Thanks
Roy